# Android C++ and NOT C

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to decide if using C++ to create an Android app is sensible. I've tried to use Java for what I want, but it simply doesn't have the language features I need.

I see a bunch of things written as C/C++, but everyone of them are actually 'C' examples.

I'd like to build a simple C++ app (NOT 'C') to better understand how to do this in Android. I've read some about the NDK which seems to support C++, but I don't know to what extent.

Is there a sample C++ project out there? One that has real C++ and not C code inside a .cpp file? An "Hello World" program would be fine. Simple is good to start.

Please pass by this question if you want to answer with how C++ wraps a 'C' function. If the example doesn't address name mangling, it's not C++. No extern 'C' please. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: which essential language features do you need which C++ has but Java doesn't?

Comment: If you want to use system calls (e.g. sockets) you have to use the standard system calls which are all old C-style functions. Also, all statements like `if` and loops look the same in both languages as C++ is derived from C.

Comment: @Howard: The feature of everything written in Java takes four times as much characters as in C++ would be a good answer. And if nothing else; auto.

Comment: Re: C++/Java.  In my case I need to do Meta-programming. So I'm looking to use the Boost mpl and pre-preprocessor libraries. I don't know of any similar libraries in Java. Someday I'd also like to port to iPhone (if Android version is successful). From what I read, C++ can be used in both platforms, Java not so much.

Answer (score 3):

NDK works really fine. It is so simple that you have your .cpp and .h written in C++, compile them with ndk-build, and you have your android code including the cpp's like explained this [tutorial](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/05/android-introduction-part-2-setting-up-your-environment/) shows:

Good luck:
[Part 1](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/05/android-sdk-ndk-part-1-setting-up-your-environment/)
[Part 2](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/05/android-introduction-part-2-setting-up-your-environment/)

Official documentation: [Sample applications](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples)

Comment: Looks good at first glance. I'll need to read it fully to be sure. Thanks, I didn't find this.

Comment: This is not C++. Anyone else have an pure C++ example?